# Low Quality -> Length and content

Tags: discussion

I saw [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/64270/chip-atm-cards-and-mexico) question flagged as low quality because of length and content. I thought the question was direct, so it didn't need to be any longer than it was. I see many posts flagged for the same reason that are direct questions or answers.

It seems like it is an abuse of the flagging system if every short question/answer is flagged. Sometimes a downvote is more appropriate if you don't think enough thought or background was put into the question. What do the rest of you think?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any explicit flags from users on this post - I think it entered the review system automatically because of the length.

That's a policy decision from StackExchange as a whole that we couldn't easily change, but anyway it makes some sense to me as there's often a correlation between really short questions and bad content, even if it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: I didn't realize that it wasn't a flag. I'm viewing on a smartphone with limited access.

Answer (score 1):

I think the flagging process is tough. 
The particular question cited is not a good one in my opinion, but not due to its length. It seems a question the OP should ask his bank.

To the bigger picture, anyone over a very low threshold can flag, and more often than not, I'd prefer they used the voting system. I usually decline with the "mod attention not required" response.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful OP's bank would be about needing a chip in a card top use it in a foreign country so I think that it is a good question - for the travel SE! I only ever flag spam, and that's just to get it deleted quickly just in case someone falls for it, and otherwise downvote in agreement with your point.